# Replacing app.UseMvc() with app.UserRouting() gives us error `The request matched multiple endpoints`

Tags: c#, routes, .net-6.0

We use attribute routing as follows to differentiate V1 and V2 versions of our api. We are upgrading to .NET 6.

We have remove the `app.UserMvc()` and replaced with

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(opts =>
{
    opts.MapControllers();
 });
```

The V2 controller looks like this

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
...
```

and the V1 controller looks like this

```
[Obsolete]
[ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = true)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
```

But we get this error now

```
The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 
Api.V1.Controllers.UserToDestinationMapController.GetAllDestinations (Jet2.OverseasOps.UserManagement.Api)
Api.V2.Controllers.UserToDestinationMapController.GetAllDestinations (Jet2.OverseasOps.UserManagement.Api)
```

How can we get it working again like when using the `app.UseMvc()`

Comment: have you tried removing `[Route("api/[controller]")]` ?

Comment: @viveknuna Yes I've tried that as well and just had the V1 and V2 routing and no change

Comment: and what about `{version:apiVersion}`, are you sure that it gives a different value? just try once by hard-coding v1 and v2

Comment: @viveknuna hard coding the Version in the Route seems to work! hmm interesting, Think that answers that issues just need to now figure out why swagger as stopped working, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So vivek nuna helped with the initial issue, removing the `{version:apiVersion}` and trying with a hard coded string like `[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]` did make it work.

There were other issues, so after ripping it down to the basics and starting from the ground it, it seems all config related; so I will try and explain what works for me.

Add this to the `IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in the Startup.cs file (we are using service fabric to host it but imagine it will be close to this). The key bit for me was the `setup.ApiVersionReader` which helped remove the need to provide an api version as a parameter is swagger.

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddControllersAsServices()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    });

services.AddOptions();

services.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
{
    setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    setup.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    setup.ReportApiVersions = true;
    setup.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
        new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
        new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
});

services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

services.AddSwaggerGen();
services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
```

We also had this class which is used above:

```
public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
{
    private readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider _provider;

    public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        // add swagger document for every API version discovered
        foreach (var description in _provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc(
                description.GroupName,
                CreateVersionInfo(description));
        }
    }

    public void Configure(string name, SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        Configure(options);
    }

    private OpenApiInfo CreateVersionInfo(
        ApiVersionDescription description)
    {
        var info = new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "Jet2 Overseas Ops User Management Api",
            Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString()
        };

        if (description.IsDeprecated)
        {
            info.Description += " This API version has been deprecated.";
        }

        return info;
    }
}
```

Inside the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)` method of the Startup.cs file we have the below. The issue bit for me was the `options.SwaggerEndpoint`, where you we had to specify `./` at the start of the path.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionLoggingMiddleware>();

    app.UseNoResponseCaching();
    
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"./{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(opts =>
    {
        opts.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

We also decorate the controller class like this

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class RoleController : ControllerBase {
... 
}
```

Nothing special added to the methods apart from the usual `HttpPost`, `HttpGet` etc... Attributes.