# Swashbuckle Swagger asking for api-version?

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

We have implemented api versioning as mentioned here https://referbruv.com/blog/integrating-aspnet-core-api-versions-with-swagger-ui/

But why are we getting this api-version fields when it should know that it is version 2?

[image]

I have decorated the endpoint with the following yet it still displays this api-version field?

```
[HttpGet("summary/all")]
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
```

I have also done the same for the v2 endpoint but change to 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the **ApiVersionReader** seemed to correct this:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
{
    setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    setup.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    setup.ReportApiVersions = true;
    setup.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
        new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
        new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
});
```

A full example of what works for me can be found as the answer in this question [Replacing app.UseMvc() with app.UserRouting() gives us error `The request matched multiple endpoints`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74860541/replacing-app-usemvc-with-app-userrouting-gives-us-error-the-request-matche)